# Antlr - decision matching with multiple alternatives

Tags: c#, antlr, lexer

I'm trying to get a match to work for the following rule which will match operator identifiers, but it's not having it, specifically on the lines that match `==` and `..`:

```
Symbol
    :   (   U_Sm
        |   U_So
        |   U_Sc
        |   '\u0080' .. '\u007F'
        |   '==' '='*
        |   '..' '.'*
        )+
    ;
```

The rules with `U_` prefixes refer to unicode group lexer fragments. I have removed the `=` character from the `U_Sm` fragment, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Valid identifiers could be the following:

- `==`
- `!==`
- `<<~`
- `..`
- `!..`
- `<...`
- `±϶⇎`

Invalid identifiers would be:

- `.` (Member access is done separately)
- `=` (Assignment is done separately)
- `!.` (Single dots or single equals signs in an identifier are disallowed)

As you can see, the rule can include two or more equals signs or full stops in an identifier (e.g. `!..`, `<...>`, `!==`) or as the whole identifier (e.g. `..`, `==`, `===`), but not one.

The errors and warnings given by the compiler are the following:

```
warning(200): Hydra.g3:6:18: Decision can match input such as "'='<EOT>" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input

warning(200): Hydra.g3:7:18: Decision can match input such as "'.'<EOT>" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input

error(201): Hydra.g3:8:9: The following alternatives can never be matched: 4
```

A test grammar to reproduce the errors:

```
grammar Test;

program :
    Symbol
    ;

Symbol
    :   (   U_Sm
        |   U_So
        |   U_Sc
        |   '\u0080' .. '\u007F'
        |   '==' '='*
        |   '..' '.'*
        )+
    ;

fragment U_Sm
    :   '\u002B'
    | '\u003C' | '\u003E' 
    | '\u007C' | '\u007E'
    | '\u00AC' | '\u00B1'
    | '\u00D7' | '\u00F7'
    | '\u03F6'
    | '\u0606' .. '\u0608' 
    | '\u2044' | '\u2052'
    | '\u207A' .. '\u207C' 
    | '\u208A' .. '\u208C' 
    | '\u2140' .. '\u2144' 
    | '\u214B'
    | '\u2190' .. '\u2194' 
    | '\u219A' | '\u219B'
    | '\u21A0' | '\u21A3'
    | '\u21A6' | '\u21AE'
    | '\u21CE' | '\u21CF'
    | '\u21D2' | '\u21D4'
    | '\u21F4' .. '\u22FF' 
    | '\u2308' .. '\u230B' 
    | '\u2320' | '\u2321'
    | '\u237C'
    | '\u239B' .. '\u23B3' 
    | '\u23DC' .. '\u23E1' 
    | '\u25B7' | '\u25C1'
    | '\u25F8' .. '\u25FF' 
    | '\u266F'
    | '\u27C0' .. '\u27C4' 
    | '\u27C7' .. '\u27CA' 
    | '\u27CC'
    | '\u27D0' .. '\u27E5' 
    | '\u27F0' .. '\u27FF' 
    | '\u2900' .. '\u2982' 
    | '\u2999' .. '\u29D7' 
    | '\u29DC' .. '\u29FB' 
    | '\u29FE' .. '\u2AFF' 
    | '\u2B30' .. '\u2B44' 
    | '\u2B47' .. '\u2B4C' 
    | '\uFB29' | '\uFE62'
    | '\uFE64' .. '\uFE66' 
    | '\uFF0B'
    | '\uFF1C' .. '\uFF1E' 
    | '\uFF5C' | '\uFF5E'
    | '\uFFE2'
    | '\uFFE9' .. '\uFFEC' 
    ;

fragment U_So
    :   '\u00A6' | '\u00A7'
    | '\u00A9' | '\u00AE'
    | '\u00B0' | '\u00B6'
    | '\u0482' | '\u060E'
    | '\u060F' | '\u06E9'
    | '\u06FD' | '\u06FE'
    | '\u07F6' | '\u09FA'
    | '\u0B70'
    | '\u0BF3' .. '\u0BF8' 
    | '\u0BFA' | '\u0C7F'
    | '\u0CF1' | '\u0CF2'
    | '\u0D79'
    | '\u0F01' .. '\u0F03' 
    | '\u0F13' .. '\u0F17' 
    | '\u0F1A' .. '\u0F1F' 
    | '\u0F34' | '\u0F36'
    | '\u0F38'
    | '\u0FBE' .. '\u0FC5' 
    | '\u0FC7' .. '\u0FCC' 
    | '\u0FCE' | '\u0FCF'
    | '\u0FD5' .. '\u0FD8' 
    | '\u109E' | '\u109F'
    | '\u1360'
    | '\u1390' .. '\u1399' 
    | '\u1940'
    | '\u19E0' .. '\u19FF' 
    | '\u1B61' .. '\u1B6A' 
    | '\u1B74' .. '\u1B7C' 
    | '\u2100' | '\u2101'
    | '\u2103' .. '\u2106' 
    | '\u2108' | '\u2109'
    | '\u2114'
    | '\u2116' .. '\u2118' 
    | '\u211E' .. '\u2123' 
    | '\u2125' | '\u2127'
    | '\u2129' | '\u212E'
    | '\u213A' | '\u213B'
    | '\u214A' | '\u214C'
    | '\u214D' | '\u214F'
    | '\u2195' .. '\u2199' 
    | '\u219C' .. '\u219F' 
    | '\u21A1' | '\u21A2'
    | '\u21A4' | '\u21A5'
    | '\u21A7' .. '\u21AD' 
    | '\u21AF' .. '\u21CD' 
    | '\u21D0' | '\u21D1'
    | '\u21D3'
    | '\u21D5' .. '\u21F3' 
    | '\u2300' .. '\u2307' 
    | '\u230C' .. '\u231F' 
    | '\u2322' .. '\u2328' 
    | '\u232B' .. '\u237B' 
    | '\u237D' .. '\u239A' 
    | '\u23B4' .. '\u23DB' 
    | '\u23E2' .. '\u23E8' 
    | '\u2400' .. '\u2426' 
    | '\u2440' .. '\u244A' 
    | '\u249C' .. '\u24E9' 
    | '\u2500' .. '\u25B6' 
    | '\u25B8' .. '\u25C0' 
    | '\u25C2' .. '\u25F7' 
    | '\u2600' .. '\u266E' 
    | '\u2670' .. '\u26CD' 
    | '\u26CF' .. '\u26E1' 
    | '\u26E3'
    | '\u26E8' .. '\u26FF' 
    | '\u2701' .. '\u2704' 
    | '\u2706' .. '\u2709' 
    | '\u270C' .. '\u2727' 
    | '\u2729' .. '\u274B' 
    | '\u274D'
    | '\u274F' .. '\u2752' 
    | '\u2756' .. '\u275E' 
    | '\u2761' .. '\u2767' 
    | '\u2794'
    | '\u2798' .. '\u27AF' 
    | '\u27B1' .. '\u27BE' 
    | '\u2800' .. '\u28FF' 
    | '\u2B00' .. '\u2B2F' 
    | '\u2B45' | '\u2B46'
    | '\u2B50' .. '\u2B59' 
    | '\u2CE5' .. '\u2CEA' 
    | '\u2E80' .. '\u2E99' 
    | '\u2E9B' .. '\u2EF3' 
    | '\u2F00' .. '\u2FD5' 
    | '\u2FF0' .. '\u2FFB' 
    | '\u3004' | '\u3012'
    | '\u3013' | '\u3020'
    | '\u3036' | '\u3037'
    | '\u303E' | '\u303F'
    | '\u3190' | '\u3191'
    | '\u3196' .. '\u319F' 
    | '\u31C0' .. '\u31E3' 
    | '\u3200' .. '\u321E' 
    | '\u322A' .. '\u3250' 
    | '\u3260' .. '\u327F' 
    | '\u328A' .. '\u32B0' 
    | '\u32C0' .. '\u32FE' 
    | '\u3300' .. '\u33FF' 
    | '\u4DC0' .. '\u4DFF' 
    | '\uA490' .. '\uA4C6' 
    | '\uA828' .. '\uA82B' 
    | '\uA836' | '\uA837'
    | '\uA839'
    | '\uAA77' .. '\uAA79' 
    | '\uFDFD' | '\uFFE4'
    | '\uFFE8' | '\uFFED'
    | '\uFFEE' | '\uFFFC'
    | '\uFFFD'
    ;

fragment U_Sc
    :   '\u0024'
    |   '\u00A2' .. '\u00A5'
    |   '\u060B' | '\u09F2'
    |   '\u09F3' | '\u09FB'
    |   '\u0AF1' | '\u0BF9'
    |   '\u0E3F' | '\u17DB'
    |   '\u20A0' .. '\u20B8'
    |   '\uA838' | '\uFDFC'
    |   '\uFE69' | '\uFF04'
    |   '\uFFE0' | '\uFFE1'
    |   '\uFFE5' | '\uFFE6'
    ;
```

Comment: Hi Bart, I've uploaded a test grammar to google docs

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look later on. Note that it's preferable to post the grammar here on SO instead of using an external link, which may disappear, making your question (and possible answers) incomplete.

Comment: Bart, the unicode groups cause the grammar to be 4kb, i'm not sure SO will allow such a large code block! Also, thank you for your time again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range `'\u0080' .. '\u007F'` is invalid since `0x80` is larger than `0x7F`.

It seems ANTLR has a problem with your nested repetition: `( ... ( ... )+ ... )+`. Even though ANTLR's `+` and `*` are greedy by default (except for `.*` and `.+`), it appears that in such nested repetitions you need to explicitly tell ANTLR to either match ungreedy or greedy (greedy in your case).

The following rule does not produce any errors:

```java
Symbol
  :  ( U_Sm
     | U_So
     | U_Sc
     | '\u007F' .. '\u0080'
     | '==' (options{greedy=true;}: '=')*
     | '..' (options{greedy=true;}: '.')*
     )+
  ;
```

Comment: How the hell did I miss that 7F-80 group! And you're a genius! I knew it was to do with the inner groups, I tried the greedy option before but must have gone wrong somewhere! Thank you very much

Comment: In fact it was originally 20-7F (Brought from either PHP or Scala identifiers), turns out I didn't want that line anyway, thanks for alerting me to that!

Comment: "... using multiple alternatives: 1, 2" What does 1, 2 mean? Where do they point?

Comment: @iuliux, a parser rule consists of one or more alternative parses. Take parser rule `r` for example: `r : A | B | C;`, which consists of 3 alternatives: `A`, `B` and `C`.